# jQuery to dynamically add classes to a nested list item to flag menus that have child nodes

Tags: jquery

The markup below is an example of a dynamically generated menu that is styled with css as a flyout. I'm just trying to add arrows to show where menus have child menus.

Is it possible, via jQuery, to add a class ("hasChild top") to the top level elements that have submenus and a class ("hasChild sub") to the lower level elements that have children?

```
<ul id="menu-site-menu">
    <li"><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Our Charity Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Buy Apparel</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Benevolent Elephant</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Benevolent Elephant Short Sleeve</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Benevolent Elephant Long Sleeve</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Eagle-Spirit</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Eagle-Spirit Short Sleeve</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Eagle-Spirit Long Sleeve T-Shirts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

So. in this example, the jQuery would add the "hasChild top" class to "About Us" and "Buy Apparel"

It would add the "hasChild sub" class to "Benevolent Elephant" and "Eagle Spirit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var topLevel = $("ul.nav.menu > li").has("ul");
topLevel.addClass("hasChild top");
topLevel.find("li").has("ul").addClass("hasChild sub");
```

That is, find the li elements that are direct descendants of the top ul, then use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to narrow it down to only those that contain a child ul. Give them the "hasChild top" classes. Then, within those top level ones use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in combination with `.has()` to get all lower level menus (no matter how deeply nested) and give them the "hasChild sub" classes.

Comment: `$("ul.nav.menu > li").has("ul").addClass("hasChild top").find("li").has("ul").addClass("hasChild sub");` does the same thing :)

Comment: @Stefan - Of course! I should've known that. That is, I _did_ know that, but just didn't think of it originally. Oops. Thanks for doing the jsFiddle.

Comment: +1. Looks great. Testing it now. Also +1 for Stefan's shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will probably work just fine.

```
$('ul.nav.menu > li').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) $(this).addClass('hasChild').addClass('top');
});

$('ul.nav.menu > li > ul > li').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) $(this).addClass('hasChild').addClass('sub');
});
```

Comment: `addClass()` can set both classes at the same time by separating the classes with a white space. `addClass('hasChild top')`.

Comment: Nice, but it seems like nnnnnn's solution is much better. :) I will take a closer look at the .has(), could be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.nav.menu > li > ul > li').each(function { 
    if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) $(this).addClass('hasChild').addClass('sub'); 
    else 
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('hasChild').addClass('top'); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best jquery but this should do the trick:

```
  $('.menu > li').each(function() {
        var childMenu = $(this).find('ul');
        if (childMenu.length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('hasChild top');

            var subMenuChild = $('.hasChild.top > ul > li');
            $(subMenuChild).each(function() {
                var subMenuChildMenu = $(this).find('ul');
                if (subMenuChildMenu.length > 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('hasChild sub');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue and I think my answer is in here.

First I have a flyout nested list(s) that are outputed as .hasChildren from a hosted service.
So, I can only add classes to the UL, and those work just fine.

What I'm looking to do is .append a span class to the .hasChildren (not add a class)
I've tried some of the code above and it keeps appending the span class to the end of the list - see what I want to achieve below in bold.

Originally I worked this out

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('li.hasChildren a').first().append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

$('ul ul li.hasChildren a').first().append('');
    });

It works, but I have nested lists and some of the lists will have multiple nestings at varies times as the site can have pages added dynamically by the customer in the admin on the CMS - so I can't work with just the .first

**This is what I want to achieve**

```
<li class="hasChildren"><a href="/about-us" class="">About Us<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
```

Here is the outputted code from the CMS:

```
<ul class="globalMenu sf-menu responsive-menu sf-js-enabled">
   <li class="selectedPage"><a href="/" class="selectedPage">Home</a></li>
   <li class="hasChildren"><a href="/about-us" class="">About Us</a>
         <ul class="level2" style="display: none;">
                 <li><a href="/our-team">Our Team</a></li>
                 <li class="hasChildren"><a href="/campaigns" class="">Campaigns</a>
                          <ul class="level3" style="display: none;">
                                   <li><a href="/beat-poverty">Beat Poverty</a></li>
                         </ul>
                  </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="/how-to-help">how to help</a></li>
```

P.S.
I like the length as the page structure can change at any time.
CK

UPDATE:

Went thru all the above code and this is what I came up with that works.
The only thing that would be nice is for a way to count thru all the nested lists rather than keep adding another for each (or separate with commas). Let me know if there is an easier way for this or if this is the easiest way that I worked out.

```
$('ul.globalMenu > li.hasChildren > a').append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

$('ul.globalMenu > li.hasChildren ul li.hasChildren > a').append('');